# rxjs: use stream referring twice to an observable that has already completed upstream

Tags: javascript, stream, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactivex

I'm having problems with getting a value from a hot observable after it's been used.

```js
const partialState$ = Rx.Observable.of(1)
.publish().refCount();

const downstreamState$ = partialState$.map(v => ([v+1, v+2]));

const finalState$ = downstreamState$
// last value of partialState$ being requested -
// shouldn't matter if its completed through earlier chaining
.withLatestFrom(partialState$)
  
finalState$.subscribe(state => {  // this does not fire
 console.log('state', state);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.0-rc.5/Rx.js"></script>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j64te6jp/10/

The code above does nothing - it seems like due to synchronous behaviour of subscribe, `partialState$` isn't marked as having a value ready until pushed into `.subscribe`
which never happens because no value exists yet for `partialState$` when `downStreamState$` requests the latest from it.

Could someone please explain why is this happening and also provide a good method of re-using the same value from a hot (published) observable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solutions suggested to me - many thanks to https://github.com/Dorus

```js
const partialState$ = Rx.Observable.of(1)
.do(() => console.log('i will be run once'))

const finalState$ = partialState$.publish(partialState_ => {
 const downstreamState$ = partialState_.map(v => ([v+1, v+2]));
 return downstreamState$
  .withLatestFrom(partialState_)
})
  
finalState$.subscribe(state => {
 console.log('state', state);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.0-rc.5/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you subscribe after the value was emitted. Why not use the `.publishReplay()`?

If you still want to avoid `publishReplay()`, you can use `.delay(0)`:

```
const partialState$ = Rx.Observable.of(1).delay(0)
  .publish().refCount();
```

Comment: That's a good option, but wouldn't it change the execution order due to asynchronicity (like here http://jsfiddle.net/j64te6jp/8/)?I wish there was a way to have the best of both.
I'd like to avoid `replay` to also avoid storing extra state I don't really need to store

Comment: It would make the value available in the next cycle, by that time your subscription will be active. I tried it in your fiddle and it worked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j64te6jp/8/
Indeed, that works, but I still feel like that should be a better way considering that the value **is** ready in the very first cycle.

Comment: It is, but if you register after it was ready, you can't see it (unless you use replay)

Comment: The stream is not hot as `publish().refCount()` is being used. Therefore the value from `partialState$` should not be emitted until it is first subscribed to by `finalState$` in any event. The (more complex) issue and question is: when referring to an observable that has already been consumed somewhere upstream within that same stream, e.g., to 'bring the value back in' to the stream at some downstream point, why doesn't `.withLatestFrom` fire and let the stream complete at all.

Comment: The expected behavior would be that on subscription to `finalState$`, the chained streams go back to pull the single value out of `partialState$`, and then re-reference this extracted value from the completed observable at the `withLatestFrom` step, and so that this would work with `publish().refCount()` as only a single source is desired. However, this does not work unless `withLatestFrom` step is removed. Hence my interest in this question also.